# How can we schedule task for 24 hours to get executed and store response in a variable for 24 hours?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am making post request to an api once in 24 hours and I want to store token received after post request in one variable which am using further.( Token value is valid for 24 hours) I want the same value for 24 hours. Please suggest me an efficient way of implementing this using springboot.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to store, text, json, http response? It's probably a better idea to store the response as text in a database with columns for the task response and a timestamp. You can then programatically determen via the time stamp if a response has been stored for 24 hours by comparing it with the current date and time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am receiving a token and and I want to to store it as a string but I am not using any database. Can you suggest any efficient way of doing this in springboot?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can accomplish this behaviour, but since you want to use Spring, I think you should declare a Bean which will store your token (in a volatile field), while also having a scheduled task for updating it every 24h. I mentioned using a Bean because you can then inject it into other services, so you don't have to resort to using a static field for sharing the value with other services.